# Replacing Python negatives with 0 without Conditional operator and Python conditionals

Tags: python, numpy, operators

I want to detect a negative number and replace it with 0

```
a = np.arange(10)
b=np.where(a<5,a,-1*a)
b[b<0]=0  #conditional operator '<' 
b
```

gives output

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Is there a way to do it without using '<' operator or Python conditionals (if-else)

Comment: Why do you want to do it without `<`? What is wrong with your approach?

Comment: If your '<' key is not working, use `np.less(a, 5)` instead of `a<5`

Comment: @mathfux understood my problem (lol). I was using on-screen keyboard to type this code which is really inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clip()` method of `np.array`. The function `clip()` takes minimum value and maximum value to clip. It requires at least one of them. You can just provide a value of `0` to be considered as the lower bound.

```
>>> b.clip(0)
>>> b
```

#### Output

---

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```